# How to configure SpecFlow to work with [DoNotParallelize] attribute from MS Test v2?

Tags: mstest, specflow

Using SpecFlow together with MS Test v2, how can I use `[DoNotParallelize]` attribute from MS Test framework to mark a SpecFlow scenario or a feature as one that I don't want to run in parallel?

Seems that this feature is already implemented here https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/996 but I cannot figure out how to use it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

With trial and errors I managed to figure out how it works.

So the annotation you need to use in .feature file is "`@mstest:donotparallelize`"

**If you want to make a scenario not run in parallel:**
[image]

**If you want to make the whole feature not run in parallel:**
[image]

**In the .feature.cs file it generates something like this:**
[image]

As you can see it also adds a category (tag) to scenarios that are marked with this attribute but I guess it's not a problem at all!